# Unable to select for update the correct row when SKIP LOCKED is used in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading

I am facing a problem in MySQL 8.0x with SKIP LOCKED.

The table is something like this (over simplified)

```
Table users as U {
  id int [pk, increment] // auto-increment
  transaction_id int
  full_name varchar
  status int
  created_at timestamp
  country_code int
  important varchar
```

}

There are plenty of rows there and multiple threads writing concurrently at the table.

Initially I am selecting a row for update

> SELECT * FROM Table WHERE STATUS=0 AND IMPORTANT="QgBv0kidCvg"  AND
>   country_code=17200 AND TRANSACTION_ID < 0 ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1 FOR
>   UPDATE **SKIP LOCKED**

Then with the update statement I am reserving the row with a temporarily status code, so if another thread has the same query parameters now rows will be returned to the second thread.

> UPDATE Table SET STATUS=3 WHERE ID=4695

The code does a few integrations here and there and at the end, after the reservation is OK I am

finalizing the status value to 1

> UPDATE Table SET STATUS=1, TRANSACTION_ID=2312313 WHERE ID=4695

So it is a reservation scenario where a request comes to check if there is a free "important", reserves it for a while changing the status to 3 ( a temp state ) and after the peers are updated we mark the row with status = 1 means that it is reserved.

My problem here is that the SKIP LOCKED statement returns NO ROWS, meaning that no rows were found free. There is no chance of two concurrent threads querying for the some row. I checked this several times.

What concerns me here is that **if I remove the SKIP LOCKED** at the end of the select for update statement everything works as expected.

Comment: When you use the query with SKIP LOCKED the server firstly queries, then skips - and, because the record selected is locked, the resultset is empty.

If you'll remove SKIP LOCKED then the second process will hang until the first process commits its transaction.

Comment: But as I described in my situation the processes go to different rows, so I was expecting that both processes will return different table rows

Comment: No. *SKIP LOCKED causes a FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE query to execute immediately, excluding rows from the result set that are locked by another transaction.* - this is performed AFTER the query execution, over its output. If you think that the locked records will be skipped during the quering then you make a mistake. Simply try `LIMIT 2 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` - and you'll receive one non-locked record which is 2nd in current ordering.

Comment: @Akina thanks, I agree with you. This is why I added the SKIP LOCKED in order to have 1 row selected per query. However the problem here is that it works without SKIP LOCKED. Moreover when SKIP LOCKED is used there is no row returned even if the query param is used by only 1 process..

Comment: Can you add your isolation level as well as details about any indexes apart from the pk (or confirming you dont have any)? Depending on those details, MySQL can lock more than just one row.

Comment: I don't have indexes. Just a simple table with PK